# MPI Segmentation fault error when use very large array

Tags: arrays, sum, mpi

I'm trying to wrote a MPI program with C++, to sum the values of a very large array. 
The code below works well with array dimension up to 1 million, but when I try to execute with 10 million elements or more, I receive a sigmentation error. Someone can help me? Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double t0, t1, time; //variabili per il calcolo del tempo
int nprocs, myrank;
    int root=0;
long temp, sumtot, i, resto, svStartPos, dim, intNum;

//Dimensione del vettore contenente i valori da sommare
const long A_MAX=10000000;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);


    long vett[A_MAX];
long parsum[B_MAX];

long c=-1;
int displs[nprocs];
int sendcounts[nprocs];

//printf("B_MAX: %ld\n", B_MAX);

//Inviamo (int)(A_MAX/nprocs) elementi tramite una scatter, resto è il 
//numero di elementi restanti che verranno inviati tramite la scatterv
resto= A_MAX % nprocs;
//printf("Resto: %d\n", resto);

//Posizione da cui iniziare lo Scatterv
svStartPos = A_MAX - resto;
//printf("svStartPos: %d\n", svStartPos);

// numero di elementi per processore senza tener conto del resto 
dim= (A_MAX-resto)/nprocs; 
//printf("dim: %d\n", dim);

//Il processore 0 inizializza il vettore totale, del quale vogliamo
//calcolare la somma
if (myrank==0){
    for (i=0; i<A_MAX; i++)
        vett[i]=1;
}

//Ciascun processore inizializza il vettore locale del quale calcoleremo la
//somma parziale dei suoi elementi. tale somma parziale verrà utilizzata
//nell'operazione di reduce
for (i=0; i<B_MAX; i++)
    parsum[i]=-1;

//Ciascun processore inizializza i vettori sendcounts e displs necessari per
//l'operazione di scatterv
for (i=0; i<nprocs; i++){
    if (i<A_MAX-svStartPos){
        //Se il rank del processore è compreso tra 0 e resto ...
        sendcounts[i]=1;            //...verrà inviato 1 elemento di vett...
        displs[i]= svStartPos+i;    //...di posizione svStartPos+i
    }
    else {
        //se il rank del processore è > resto ...
        sendcounts[i]=0;            //...non verrà inviato alcun elemento
        displs[i]= A_MAX;           
    }
}

root = 0;    //Il processore master

sumtot = 0;  //Valore della domma totale degli elementi di vett
temp = 0;    //valore temporaneo delle somme parziali

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if (A_MAX>=nprocs){
   MPI_Scatter(&vett[dim*myrank], dim, MPI_LONG, &parsum, dim, MPI_LONG, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   printf("Processore: %d - Scatter\n", myrank);
}

//La scatterv viene effettuata solo dai processori che hanno il rank 
//0<myrank<resto
if (sendcounts[myrank]==1){       
   MPI_Scatterv(&vett,sendcounts,displs,MPI_LONG,&c,1,MPI_LONG,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
   parsum[B_MAX-1]=c; 
   printf("Processore: %d - effettuo la Scatterv\n", myrank);
} 

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if(myrank==0){
    t0 = MPI_Wtime(); //inizio conteggio tempo
}

for(i=0; i<B_MAX; i++){
    if (parsum[i]!=-1)     
        temp = temp + parsum[i]; //somma degli elementi 
}
printf("Processore: %d - Somma parziale: %ld\n", myrank, temp);

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

//il risultato di somma di ogni processore viene mandato al root che somma 
//i risultati parziali
MPI_Reduce(&temp,&sumtot,1,MPI_LONG,MPI_SUM,root,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if(myrank==0){
    t1 = MPI_Wtime(); //stop al tempo

    //calcolo e stampa del tempo trascorso
    time = 1.e6 * (t1-t0);
    printf("NumProcessori: %d  Somma: %ld  Tempo: %f\n", nprocs, sumtot, time);

    //verifica del valore somma. Se è corretto sumtot è pari a 0.
    sumtot = sumtot - A_MAX;
    printf("Verifica: %ld\n", sumtot);
}

MPI_Finalize();

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The first real error I found was this line:

```
MPI_Scatterv(&vett,sendcounts,displs,MPI_LONG,&c,1,MPI_LONG,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Which passes the address of an `::std::vector<int>` to a function that expects a `void*` in that argument. The conversion of any pointer type (like `::std::vector<int>*`) to `void*` is allowed as an implicit conversion, so there are no compile errors at this point. However, [MPI_Scatterv](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Scatterv.html) expects its first argument to be the address of the send buffer, which MPI expects to be a normal array.

I guess that you changed your code recently from the commented out sections, where `vett` is an array and tried to get your call to work by adding the address-of operator in your `MPI_Scatterv` call. The original array probably caused segfaults at some point since it was stack-allocated and you ran out of stack space with those monsters (default stack size on linux systems is on the order of megabytes iirc, which would exactly fit that assumption - test this with [ulimit -s](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html)).

The change to `::std::vector<int>` caused the actual data to be placed on the heap instead, which has a much larger maximum size (and on 64 bit systems you can expect to run out of physical memory much earlier). You actually already implemented a solution to your particular problem a few lines earlier:

```
MPI_Scatter(&vett[dim*myrank], dim, MPI_LONG, &parsum, dim, MPI_LONG, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Here, you access an element and then take its address (note that `[]` [binds tighter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `&`). This is O.K. as long as you do not modify the underlying `vector`. If you just apply that solution to the previous call, you can solve this problem quite easily:

```
MPI_Scatterv(&vett[0],sendcounts,displs,MPI_LONG,&c,1,MPI_LONG,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

In any case, except for the two `vector` objects, your code looks like it was written for the old C standard, not C++ - for example you might consider having a look into things like the [`new` operator family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_%28C%2B%2B%29) instead of `malloc.h`, you can put your variable declarations in line with their definitions (even inside [`for` loop headers](http://www.intap.net/~drw/cpp/cpp04_03.htm)!), ease your life with using the `ostream` [cout](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) instead of `printf`...

Comment: Sorry, the original program was different. I update the question with the original version of my code... 
Unfortunately if I try to use new operator I have compilation error, because I'm running this program on a cluster, and I don't know which version of compilator it uses.
So.. How can I  manage these arrays without support of vector?

Comment: if you can compile the code with `vector` you probably have access to the new operator.... did you have a look at the stack limit vs. the size of your two arrays...?

Comment: if I try to #include "vector.h" I receive "No such file or directory" error.
I don't know the stack limit because I run the program on the cluster of my university, and I don't have too much details of the machine..

Comment: That would be because the header is not named `"vector.h"` but `<vector>`, since we are talking about a part of the C++ standard library. Are you sure you are using C++...?

Answer (score 0):

The program seems to me a C one, since you are not using any C++ facility, or any header (which would have been **cstdio**, without **.h**).

Anyway, can you please replace the array allocation, A[very huge number], with a standard allocation? If you want C, **malloc**, otherwise, **new**. Then post the results.

This seems to be a heap allocation problem (http://c-faq.com/strangeprob/biglocal.html).

Let me know.